# null is not an object (evaluating '_RNGestureHandlerModule.default.Direction')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I followed the instructions for installing react-navigation 3.x from their website. I re-built the app and even created new project and followed the instructions again.
but still getting the same above error. any idea?

edit: I am running the app react-native cli using react-native run-ios. I am not using Xcode

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM9oM.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/494) do the following:

- Right Click Libraries "Add Files to Project"
- /node_modules/react-native-gesture-handlers/ios/RNGestureHandler.xcodeproj
- Go to build phases and add libRNGestureHandler.a
- Run

Comment: I am running the app react-native cli using react-native run-ios. I am not using Xcode. should that still help?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this is to do with the new autolinking feature in `RN 0.60`.

To fix for now just add the following podspec for RNGesureHandler to ios/Podfile

```
pod 'RNGestureHandler', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/RNGestureHandler.podspec'
```

Then in the ios directory run `pod install` to install it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this and solved by updating the pod spec and then rebuilding in Xcode.

```
# from project root
cd ios
pod update
```

Then re-run from Xcode